# add column check for format number to number oracle

Tags: oracle, addition, alter

I need to add a column to a table that check for input to be a max value of 999 to 999, like a soccer match score. How do I write this statement?

example:

```
 | Score |
 ---------
 | 1-2   |
 | 10-1  |
 |999-999|
 | 99-99 |
```

Comment: Why would you store this as a single string column, which you'll presumably need to parse frequently, rather than two numeric columns?

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but I'm a student and the question ask to be written this way. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried?  Were I forced to do something like this, I'd use regular expressions.  No idea if your class has covered that or whether it expects you to use the older `instr` and `substr` functions.

Comment: Somebody else had this homework the other day. Try searching.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d52d3/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE SCORES (Score ) AS
          SELECT '1-2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '10-1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '999-999' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '99-99' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '1000-1000' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SCORE,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( SCORE, '^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}$' )
            THEN 'Valid'
            ELSE 'Invalid'
            END AS Validity
FROM   SCORES
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2d52d3/2/0)**:

```
|     SCORE | VALIDITY |
|-----------|----------|
|       1-2 |    Valid |
|      10-1 |    Valid |
|   999-999 |    Valid |
|     99-99 |    Valid |
| 1000-1000 |  Invalid |
```